# rvalue reference to a function type

Tags: c++, rvalue

As known, the function call which return type is an rvlaue to a function is an lvalue.

> A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference
>   type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result
>   type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

```
#include <iostream>

int a(){ return 1; }

int foo(){ return 1; }

int (&&bar())(){ return a; }

int main()
{
    bar() = foo; //error: cannot convert 'int()' to 'int()' in assignment
}
```

What's wrong with that diagnostic message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emphasis mine, [expr.ass]/1:

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a
>   **modifiable** lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand...

[basic.lval]/6:

> Functions cannot be modified, but pointers to functions can be modifiable.

So you may have an lvalue referring to a function but it is not a **modifiable** lvalue, and cannot be used to modify the function.

The diagnostic message... leaves something to be desired. Clang 3.6 says,

> error: non-object type 'int ()' is not assignable

which is clearer.